# Open page in new window without popup blocking using JavaScript target _blank

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

```
var pageurl = 'http://www.my-domain.com/';
setTimeout(function() {
      url = pageurl + 'download-song/test.zip';
      window.open(url, '_blank');
      location.reload();           
 }, 3000);
```

My Current url is - `http://www.my-domain.com/song_listing.php`

I want to download `test.zip` in new window by using above code and that time my current page is reloading.

Above code is working fine. But my new tab not opening it says `Pop-up blocked`

How to fix that issue?

Comment: Generally you can only open popups from within a user initiated event - a timeout is not user initiated.

Comment: Normally, you don’t need to open links in a new tab, when that link points to something the browser can not natively display anyway. So just use `window.location.href = "path-to-your-file.zip"` – that should trigger the download dialog in all browsers, and the user will not leave the page they are currently on.

Comment: @CBroe My current url not reloading while i am using `window.location.href = "path-to-your-file.zip"`

Comment: Why do you need to reload the current URL?

Comment: @CBroe i have a cart link. i need to change it download link and also image change. can you please check - http://dev.raddyx.in/kenyan-voice/all-songs

Comment: Please describe verbally what you want/need to do, not by just pointing to some website.

Comment: @CBroe Suppose above link I want to purchase `gun gun guna re`. So i will clicking the Cart icon. After that one confirmation popup will coming `Do you want to purchase this song? Yes/No` If i will clicking yes then balance will deducted and this full song will downloading in a new tab. At that time I need to reload this page for disable popup and change the button `cart` to `download`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89164/discussion-between-chinu-and-cbroe).

Comment: Why do you need to reload the page for that – can’t you just change the appropriate parts via JS?

Comment: Its not possible. I made this code lots of pages.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research finally I found one solution. Please check -

```
var pageurl = 'http://www.my-domain.com/';
setTimeout(function() {
      url = pageurl + 'download-song/test.zip';
      window.location.href = url;
      //window.open(url, '_blank');
      setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 2000);           
 }, 3000);
```